# See error code in bat file

Tags: windows-7, prompt, batch-file

In windows prompt i am launching an app. I'd like to see the error code it returns. How do i display it?

Answer (score 3):

```
ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
```

You can also use an `IF` command to take different actions based on the value:

```
IF %ERRORLEVEL% LEQ 1 goto okay
```

Comment: As a test i wrote `calc` then `ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%` after closing normally. Do i need to set it to 0 each time or something? Why am i getting 9009? which is `DNS server not authoritative for zone.` from what visual studios error lookup is telling me.

Comment: @acidzombie24: Errorlevels are set by the individual program and don't correspond to Windows API exit codes. When I ran calc just now, I got a 0. Running a non-command-line program isn't going to set the errorlevel at the command line. What you saw was the one for an earlier command.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are running the batch file from the RUN utility in Windows.

Try this

```
runapp.bat > c:\outputlog.txt
```

This will allow you to review the output and see if there are any error messages. Alternatively, fire up Command Prompt and run the batch file from there directly.